# How to create type from JSON TypeToken

Tags: java, json, typetoken

I have following json data that I am trying to define a type using java.lang.reflect.Type and import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.

For below json

```
{
   "info":{"data1":"info1", "data2":"info2"}
}
```

I would use

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Map<String, String>>>() {}.getType();
```

Also, for below json

```
{
   "names":["name1", "name2", "name3"]
}
```

I would use

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, ArrayList<String>>>() {}.getType();
```

But, I am not so sure how to declare the type for following json

```
{
   "info":{"data1":"info1", "data2":"info2"},
   "names":["name1", "name2", "name3"]
}
```

How to declare the type using TypeToken here?

Comment: There is no type that can describe that. Deserialize to a `JsonObject` and navigate through it.

Comment: Unfortunately, using JsonObject is not an option in the environment I am working in.  It is quite frustrating...

Answer (score -1):

I played around a little bit and learned that I would not have to be very type tight.
I was able to construct an object that contains all the json data using Object type.

```
Type jSonType = new TypeToken<Object>(){}.getType();
```